# super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, super

I implement the following to build tiny yolo v2 from scratch using Keras with Tensorflow backend

My code was working fine in Keras 2.1.5
But when i updated to Keras 2.1.6 i ran in to an error

""kernel_constraint=None,

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type  ""
Please help me out
Thank you so much

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, 
Reshape, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization 

def yolo():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3), padding='same',input_shape=(416,416,3),data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(12,(1,1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))

    model.add(Reshape((13,13,2,6)))
    return model

model = yolo()
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 14):

It can be caused by working without restarting the python kernel after the update.